# Django Admin CSS missing

Tags: django, django-admin

I've been messing around with the new `collectstatic` command and have got it working for my normal pages. That is to say, I am able to load my css at this location `http://localhost:8000/static/css/main.css`. However, the css for my django admin doesn't seem to be showing up.

When I navigate to the admin css location at `http://localhost:8000/static/admin/css/base.css`, I'm getting a 404 page not found with the following error: `/home/nai/GitProjects/cats/django-trunk/django/contrib/admin/media/css/base.css" does not exist`. Looking in django-trunk, I never had the `/home/nai/GitProjects/cats/django-trunk/django/contrib/admin/media/` folder to begin with.

Is that weird?

In any case, in my static folder, there is an admin folder with the accompanying css, img and js folders which was created when I ran collectstatic and the url of the base.css seems to be pointing to that location.

This is happening on my django development server. Here are some snippets to aid in the bug hunt:

**urls**

```
 33 # In order for Dev Server to serve media files for the frontend site.
 34 urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
 35 
 36 try:
 37     if settings.DEBUG: # defined in manage.py when the first arg is "runserver"
 38         urlpatterns += patterns('',
 39         (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',{'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
 40         (r'^media-admin/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',{'document_root': os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, '..', settings.ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX)}),
 41         )
 42 except NameError:
 43     pass
```

I think it might be something to do with line 40 in my URLS file but changing media-admin to static/admin didnt help.

**settings**

```
     58 ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/admin'
     69 STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, '..', MEDIA_DIR, 'static')), '')
     70 
     71 # URL prefix for static files.
     72 # Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
         73 STATIC_URL = '/static/'
     74 
     75 # Additional locations of static files. Global files are stored in here
     76 STATICFILES_DIRS = (
     77     os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, '..', 'proj_public', 'static', 'proj')), ''),
     78     )
     79
```

Comment: the bug turned out to be related to something else entirely.. nothing wrong with the code as it turns out.

Comment: Can you please post what was the problem please. I am stuck exactly with the same issue.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Django recommends that you deploy static files with a web server other than wsgi.

1. In *settings.py*, set:

`STATIC_ROOT = 'static'`

2. Run `python manage.py collectstatic`, which will copy the Django admin static files to `/path/to/project/static/`
3. Configure your static file server. If you use Nginx, you could add this config:

   ```
   location /static/ {                              
       alias /path/to/project/static/;  
       expires modified +1w;                        
   }
   ```
4. Reload your web server

You should now have access to the static files.

Comment: alias should be till project root, static is not needed. For me this worked--> `alias /path/to/project`

Answer (score 28):

In Django 1.4 `ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX` is deprecated. Here are the steps I followed to catch up with these somewhat recent Django changes:

1. in `settings.py`, add `django.contrib.staticfiles` to `INSTALLED_APPS`
2. in `settings.py` define `STATIC_URL` — the staticfiles app won't run without it. While using `runserver` they'll get handled magically, but when you deploy, this needs to be a location where those resources can be fetched by a browser.

I think that's all there was to it.

Comment: For me, simply including 'django.contrib.staticfiles' in INSTALLED_APPS (in settings.py) fixed the problem. Everything else about my environment is basically the same as it is from the default project django generates.

Answer (score 19):

I'm using Django 1.4.3

**What did NOT work for me:**
No matter how much I edited ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX in settings.py I noticed no change in the HTML generated for the Django Admin pages.  It always says /media/admin/base.css when I view the source.

**What DID work for me.**
Copied the 'admin' folder from `/django/contrib/admin/static/` and pasted it into my projects 'media' folder

Now it works great.

Comment: Quick and dirty. Worked for me too.

Comment: You can also add `Alias /static/admin /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin` in the configuration file.

Comment: A symbolic link `ln -s /usr/local/lib/python2.7/django/contrib/admin/static/admin admin` is another option

Answer (score 13):

It seems dumb, but I actually had this exact issue and the solution was to set `DEBUG=False` to `DEBUG=True` on my local dev environment. When debug is set to False, it thinks it's in a production environment which relies on a place to put static files, such as `/var/www/html/static`, whereas the debug set to True just uses the local directory.

Answer (score 5):

Also make sure that AppDirectoriesFinder is not commented, happens when you're trying to customize your own app structure. Unfortunatelly it's pointless to seek such information in official docs.

```
STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
]
```

Answer (score 3):

just change one thing in settings.py

```
DEBUG = False # not working if you are not serve your static files for production.
```

just change

```
DEBUG = True
```

Comment: Repeat of existing answer by @Blairg23

Answer (score 2):

You need a trailing slash in your `ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX` setting.

Change to:

```
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/admin/'
```

Comment: Thanks for that but the bug was somewhere else that's related to my development environment.

Comment: Strange, the admin templates will completely bug out (links are `{{ ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX }}css/etc`) if there's no trailing slash for me.

Answer (score 1):

in my project, the solution is in `settings.py`, set:

`DEBUG = False   # debug false mod not working css`

Comment: Repeat of existing answer by @Blairg23

Answer (score 0):

I'm using chef to auto-build my django server on an AWS Ubuntu server. This post helped, but what I wound up doing was to add the directory to the package admin static pages in a local_setings.py:
https://github.com/jaycrossler/geoq-chef-repo/blob/master/cookbooks/geoq/templates/default/local_settings.py.erb#L16

```
(added to local_settings.py or to settings.py):

STATICFILES_DIRS = ('<%= node['geoq']['virtualenv']['location'] %>/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/',)
```

This resulted in local_settings.py having:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = ('/var/lib/geoq/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/',)
```

Note, that if you have other items already in your STATICFILES_DIRS, you might want to append to the list, rather than overwriting it.

Answer (score 0):

One solution might be to add your local IP to the `ALLOWED_HOSTS` list in settings.py

e.g.

```
CURRENT_IP = '192.168.0.123'
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', 'localhost', '0.0.0.0', CURRENT_IP]
```

Comment: please explain, i think this is not related?

Answer (score 0):

you need

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how it was resolved, but I took these steps when I encountered the same problem. I simply add these line in settings.py.

`ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/admin/'`

`STATICFILES_FINDERS = ( 'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder','django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder','compressor.finders.CompressorFinder', )`

i hope this will help you all.

Answer (score -3):

**In settings.py**
Don't use tuple for the

> STATICFILES_DIRS =(
>   os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
>   )

you should use list,like this

> STATICFILES_DIRS =[
>   os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
>   ]