# how to serve static/admin/ and not just static/css?

Tags: django, django-admin

After doing the `python manage.py collectstatic` I found out that I can access everything in `static/css` but not in `static/admin`. To be very clear:

1. I go to: http://mysite.com/static/admin/css/login.css and fails
2. Manually move the folder `static/admin` to `static/css`
3. I go to: http://mysite.com/static/css/admin/css/login.css and works!

Notice the change from **/static/admin/css/** to **/static/css/admin/css/** in the URLS. This means that this doesn't solve the problem because the templates continue pointing to the first URL.

I know, **serving static admin files** has been asked 100 times in stackoverflow but I still cannot make it work (and I am not alone for the comments I have read). It seems nobody has mention this weird problem of accessing the `static/css` folder and `static/anyother_folder`.

**Some extra details:**

There is no errors in the `collectstatic`, there is no problems with the application css's. This is what I have in my `settings.py`):

```
MEDIA_ROOT = join(PROJECT_ROOT,'../media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = join(PROJECT_ROOT,'../static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

I also have tried the **deprecated** `ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX` without any result.

```
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/admin/'
```

My nginx configuration is simple and clear.

```
location /static {
    alias /home/the_home/where_the_static_is/static/;
}
location /media {
    alias /home/the_home/where_the_media_is/media/;
}
```

I am using the last version of Django (1.4.2).

Comment: This question[1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7241688/django-admin-css-missing) had the same problem I am having. He said he had a problem with his environment, unfortunately didn't say what :(.

Comment: Did you make sure that django.contrib.admin was in your installed apps? Collectstatic won't copy the files if it isn't.

Comment: Thanks. django.contrib.admin is there. collectstatic is working perfectly. It places the files in static/admin, which for a non understood reason I cannot access.

Comment: please enable logging and post snippet of where nginx is looking when you request http://mysite.com/static/admin/css/login.css

Comment: Thanks, I finally found what was happening. Thanks for pointing me out to the nginx again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puff. So, here it was. I had another folder in nginx redirecting the /static/admin/ to the Django installation in the virtual environment. In the organization, we use a virtual machine template that pre-configure our Django projects. So, revisiting the nginx configuration I found this:

```
location /static/admin {
   alias /path/to/virtualenvs/my_virtualenv/path_to_the_static_admin;
}
```

Apparently this worked for Django 1.3 but the path changed at some point.