# Django admin doesn't show CSS after deploiement DRF

Tags: css, iis, deployment, django-rest-framework, django-admin

I have build a web application using Django Rest Framework and React, I am using IIS for deployment. It works just fine but I have a problem when trying to deploy Django Admin. The style doesn't show. It shows this:

[image]
[image]

I have tried so many methods to add style to DRF project.

1. I used `collectstatic` and added it as application to IIS Manager
2. I activated mimetype in settings.py to accept .css
3. I tried to link css files in the to contrib/static with the /static url and added that into urls.py.

None of the above methods were able to solve my problem and I have stuck with this bug for days.
Could you help me to figure out this problem.

### settings.py config

[image]
[image]

Comment: The script and styleSheet elements will reject responses with incorrect MIME types if the server sends the response header "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff". This is a security feature that helps prevent attacks based on MIME-type confusion. This change impacts the browser's behavior when the server sends the "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff" header on its responses.

Answer (score 0):

Your `STATIC_ROOT` seems to be incorrect. In fact, it will be the place where all statics will be collect by the `collectstatic` command.
So it has to refer to a path on your server.

**You have two possibilities :**

- Build a relative path to a folder called "collected_static" or whatever name you want :
  `STATIC_ROOT = BASE_URL / 'collected_static'`
- Build an absolute path to a folder in your server like :
  `STATIC_ROOT = '/var/www/my_proj/statics`

In **development** mode, you **don't need** to collect static, because django knows how to collect dynamically.
In **production** mode, you **need** to collect static, because it will provide and group all your statics inside the specified path.

After running `python manage.py collectstatic`, what is the response ? And can you see your expected statics in the expected folder ?

Comment: I tried both methods but it didn't work, I used BASE_URL  to the collectstatic folder but still no style is showing. When I execute python manage.py collectstatic it runs normally and creates static folder in the project folder along settings.py file and I can see the static files for the admin and rest_framework

Comment: yes i did run it, and I used the absolute path in the STATIC_ROOT

Comment: Could you provide your html template ? I assume that you have added the `<link>` tag with the correct path as `{% static 'path_to_collected_static' %}`  
Maybe you are missing static configuration in your IIS conf ? Have a look on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7241688/django-admin-css-missing?rq=1)

Comment: I use React JS to implement the frontend so I didn't use html templates. Thank you for the link but I still have this issue, I added the static folder as an application in the IIS config manager and supposedly it's the way to configurate IIS

Comment: it shows me this error : **The resource at "https://url.dz/static/admin/css/base.css" has been blocked due to incorrect MIME type ("text / html") (X-Content- Type options: nosniff)**

Comment: Well you can inspect the **generated HTML** in your browser console. Find your `<link ...>` tag which causes the issue. Is the `rel` property correct ? And then, have a look on your .htaccess [following this doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Type_MIME_incorrect_pour_les_fichiers_CSS)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions and I am sorry for the late response. I implemented what you suggested (rel property is implemented in the right way) but the style is not showing yet